# Bootstrap Carousel Caption Goes Up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

All looks fine until I change my browser window size: the carousel caption goes up and gets overlaped by the right control. I would like the caption to stay at its place just changing the text size.

There is also another problem: the carousel controls get bigger when changing the browser window size.

```css
   .carousel-caption{
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: 30%;
        margin-bottom: 8%;
        padding-right: 40px;
        max-height: 100%;


    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .p1 {
    margin: auto;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-family: ClearSans-Light;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 1em transparent;
    }

        .p2 {
        font-size: 22px;
        color: white;
        text-align: right;
        }

        .position {
        font-family: ClearSans-Bold;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption my-carousel-caption">
                    <p class="p1">
                        Snail is a common name that is applied most often to land snails, terrestrial pulmonate gastropod molluscs. However, the common name "snail" is also applied to ..
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
   

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </header>
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add this: 
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
    background: none !important;
    filter: progid:none !important;
    outline: none;
}

Comment: added a shortcut of how it looks like when changing the window size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add `font-size: 3vmin;` within `.p1` and `.p2` instead of `font-size: 22px;`